# How to display Excel, PDf files from Webservice on AEM pages

Tags: aem, sling

I'm trying to do the following: The response of a webservice is an excel (a separate call for pdf) file. I need to show this file as a link on the aem-page, and whne users click the link, the browser opens (or downloads) the file.

Use case: On the customer page, there is a section with links to Order History (Excel file), Invoice(PDF file), Products catalog(Excel file). Clicking on each link, makes a call to webservice and fetches the respective file.

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With help from Scott: 
http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__xhh5-objective_therespo.html

Here's my solution:

1. From the UI, submit the action to Sling Servlet

   ```
   <form name="importFileForm" method="get" action="/services/getData">
   <input type="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit" name="bttnAction">
   </form>
   ```
2. Your Servlet class

   ```
   public class TTIGetServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
     @Override
     protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException { 
       ...
       ...
       String serviceurl = <<< your webservice url>>>
       HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().build();
       generateFile(serviceurl, httpclient, request, response);

       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/content/ttii/en/importfiletest.html");
       dispatcher.forward(request, response);        
     }
   }
   ```
3. Generate File method that pops up the file download on browser

   ```
   public static void generateFile(String serviceurl,
                               HttpClient httpclient,
                               SlingHttpServletRequest httpRequest, 
                               SlingHttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

      HttpResponse response;
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serviceURL);

      // Makes the call to WebService
      response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

      // CORE LOGIC
      if (response!=null) {
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(response.getEntity());
       String mimeType = contentType.getMimeType();

       if (mimeType.equals(MIMETYPE_JSON)) {
           // Out of context here... 
       } else {
           // SHOW THE FILE
           ServletOutputStream sos = httpResponse.getOutputStream();                
           httpResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
           httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xls");

           BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
           InputStream istream = buf.getContent();   

           sos.write(FileHelper.writeFiles(istream));                
           sos.flush();     
       }
   }
   ```

   }